# How do I exclude text within a node, when it's relative?

Tags: xpath

I need to exclude text after a pipe written in a node.

Ex:

```
<meta property="og:xx" content=" this is my text | this is text I need to exclude">
```

I'm not sure how to exclude the text after  `|`.

I know what I would say to include all the text in the div, but no idea how I would only include the text preceding the pipe, or exclude the text after/including the pipe.

```
//meta[@property='xx']//@content
```

Comment: `substring-before` function ?

Comment: Nice one @Pawel. Examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/XPath/Fonctions/substring-before

Comment: so `substring-before(//meta[@propterty='og:xx']/@content, '|')` as @Pawel suggested